# Building PyGTK- and poppler-based binaries under Windows

Tags: python, windows, gtk, pygtk, poppler

For quite some time now, I've been fighting in vain to get a software I'm working on to work under Windows. It's written in Python (the 2.x series), and although all Linux users can benefit from its GUI when they use the source package, it seems that many people who download it go for the Windows package, for which I've only been able to provide command-line binaries.

The GUI was built using Glade/GTK, and uses poppler to embed a PDF viewer. I've found various howto's in the past (I don't have them at hand right now, sorry), which I've tried to follow religiously, but I never got things to work at all.

So, is there a reliable tutorial explaining exactly how to install the needed libraries (GTK and Poppler), so that I can build the corresponding binaries for my users?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381713/how-to-install-poppler-on-windows/20521550#20521550) I just gave for another question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a window installer here: http://download.gnome.org/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.22/