# How to install poppler in ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygtk, poppler

Poppler is a PDF rendering library based on the xpdf-3.0 code base.
I have already downloaded the tar.xz file from the official site http://poppler.freedesktop.org/
But I do not know what to do with this file

Is there any command to install or run?

P.S. - I am new to linux, so I don't know a lot about it yet..

Comment: See also: [AskUbuntu: How to install poppler >= 0.73 on ubuntu 20.04 (any change since 18.04?)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1240998/327339)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you downloaded from poppler site is source code and you may not be expert enough to install it yourself. For such situations, Ubuntu and other linux distros manage packages of popular software so you don't have to go through manual installation via source code. In your case, poppler for python is available in package `python-poppler` which can be installed via Ubuntu's package manager apt.

To install poppler python bindings open terminal and run this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-poppler
```

You should have poppler available in python then.

To search for such packages in future you can do `apt-cache search poppler`. It will list down all packages you can install via apt.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. It worked fine. Was stuck because of this for a while now.

Comment: I've followed these steps and keep getting import error (No module named poppler). I'm using ubuntu 16.04. What am I missing?

Comment: @codefreak I'm trying to download and utilize the poppler package from [here] (https://poppler.freedesktop.org/). I've downloaded both the latest stable release on Dec 28, 2019 together with the poppler encoding data. I've no idea how to install them so that I can use them in python.

where do I execute the `sudo apt-get install python-poppler` on windows? cmd terminal or anaconda terminal ?

Comment: @clover I don't really know about windows much but may be this can be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381713/how-to-install-poppler-on-windows

Answer (score 31):

Not sure how it worked in 15.04, but I know in 16.04 (Xenial), the package's official name is `poppler-utils`:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/poppler-utils

And thus can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install -y poppler-utils
```

The marked answer by codefreak is not correct if you need the poppler-command-line tools, such as `pdftotext`. Also, installing Python poppler via apt-get doesn't seem to play nice if you're on a customized system, e.g. one that is running off of the Anaconda distribution.

Comment: This works for me. Note that `python-poppler` package does not have the command line utilities such as `pdftoppm`.

Answer (score 1):

Go to link below
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/focal/main/base/poppler-utils
And only click appropriate box to install

Answer (score 0):

so run these commands on you system

- step 1 `sudo apt-get update`
- step 2 `sudo apt install -y software-properties-common`
- step 3 `sudo apt update`
- step 4 `sudo add-apt-repository main`
- step 5 `sudo add-apt-repository universe`
- step 6 `sudo add-apt-repository restricted`
- step 7 `sudo add-apt-repository multiverse`
- step 8 `apt-get install -y poppler-utils`