# No module named poppler with python-poppler installed

Tags: python, importerror, poppler

please, don't mark it as duplicate, because solutions to similar questions don't work for me

My system is ubuntu 16.04, I'm using python 2.7.12

What I am trying to do, is to use pdftohtml to convert pdf files to html. It seems that I could do it with poppler.

I've installed python-poppler with sudo apt-get install and it seems installed:

```
dpkg -s python-poppler
Package: python-poppler
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: python
Installed-Size: 144
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 0.12.1-8.1
Provides: python2.7-poppler
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0), libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.8.0), libpoppler-glib8 (>= 0.18.0), python (>= 2.7), python (<< 2.8), python-gtk2 (>= 2.10.0), python-gobject (>= 2.10.1), python-cairo (>= 1.8.4)
Description: Poppler Python bindings
 This package includes Python bindings for LibPoppler.
 It is needed to run programs written in Python and using Poppler set.
 LibPoppler is a PDF rendering library based on xpdf PDF viewer, and used by
 kpdf and evince PDF viewers.
Original-Maintainer: Andrea Gasparini <gaspa@yattaweb.it>
Homepage: http://launchpad.net/poppler-python
```

however, on import poppler it throws an import error.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Comment: import poppler - that's actually everything I've written in the script. Maybe I should install something else - additionally or instead ...

Comment: Have you tried pip install poppler ?

Comment: there are no versions available. furthermore, according to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32157049/2843872 it seems excessive :(

Comment: Any chance this is what  you're looking for? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-poppler-qt4/

Comment: I think the problem was that my virtualenv hasn't been created with parameter --system-site-packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was my virtual env wasn't created with any parameters - so --no-site-packages was used as a default value. 
when I recreated it using mkvirtualenv --system-site-packages, everything is ok.

Comment: A better solution would be to install poppler into the virtual environment with `pip`