# Python 2.7: Difficulty using pypdfocr for Windows 7

Tags: python, ocr, pypdf

I am trying to use `pypdfocr` in Windows 7 with Python 2.7.

This is the ERROR Message I get when I try `pypdfocr` in `cmd`:

> C:\Users\chamar.stu>pypdfocr F:\test2.pdf Starting conversion of
>   F:\test2.pdf 'pdfimages' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file. WARNING: Could not execute
>   pdfimages to calculate DPI (try installing xpdf or po ppler?), so
>   defaulting to 300dpi Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:\users\chamar.stu\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\lib\runpy.py",
>   line 174, in _run_module_as_main ... .... ....
>
> pypdfocr\pypdfocr_tesseract.py", line 98, in _is_version_uptodate
>       ver = [int(x) for x in ver_str.split('.')] ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '00alpha'

It seems that I am missing `Poppler` or `XPDF` but I did install Poppler via [PyGoObject](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/?source=navbar) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381713/how-to-install-poppler-on-windows). I've also link `xpdf` in my environmental path as suggested [here](https://mbnuijten.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/manualinstallationxpdflakens.pdf).

Any suggestions to get me out of this little mess?

Answer (score 1):

The `pypdfocr` script is probably calling the `pdfimages` program (one of the poppler *utilities*, not the library) using the `subprocess` module.

I could not easily discern if the utilities were provided in the URI you mention.

If not, you can find pre-built ms-windows executables for the utilities e.g. [here](http://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/).

Make sure that the location where the poppler utilities are installed is in your `PATH`, so that `pypdfocr` can find it.

Comment: OK thanks -- The link to the Popple .exe on the website is down.. I have to wait for it to re-up...

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading Tesseract from version  4.0.0-beta.1(my case) to version 3.x that doesn't contain alphanumericals in the name.

`tesseract --version` #to check

The version check built into the pypdfocr package is expecting the version numbers to be integers, hence the error on `'00alpha'` (`'0-beta'` in my case)