# How include poppler to QT Creator?

Tags: c++, qt

I downloaded the archive from the official site of poppler and
Unpacked it when I tried but there is no .lib file there.
Please explain step by step how to connect a popler to QT Creator!

Comment: Add links to the downloaded file and list the steps that you've tried so far.

Comment: https://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-0.87.0.tar.xz - poppler and i just unpact this

Comment: And, how does your `.pro` file look like and how are you using this library e.g. `main.cpp`? OS?

Comment: In order to add this baggage to the pro file, you need to first compose it. But I don’t know how to do it.

Comment: So, unable to build and install the dev binaries?

Comment: CMake says it cannot find a compiler to build

Comment: What's your OS? Version?

Comment: Windows 10 - my sys

Comment: Can you try `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-poppler`? Link: https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-poppler. Also try the solutions from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381713/how-to-install-poppler-on-windows).