# How to get Poppler running on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I want to install the pdftotext library for python3. For this, I need Poppler. Now, there is a question regarding this ([How to install Poppler on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381713/how-to-install-poppler-on-windows)) but the answers do not work for me. Specifically, when I write

`conda install -c conda-forge poppler`

it tells me that it is looking for conflicts. After quite a long time, it finished successfully but when I then try to run `pip3 install pdftotext` it tells me

`...

```
C4514: '_cwscanf_s_l': unreferenced inline function has been removed
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_wconio.h(411): warning C4514: '_cwscanf_s': unreferenced inline function has been removed
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\wchar.h(180): warning C4514: 'fwide': unreferenced inline function has been removed
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\wchar.h(189): warning C4514: 'mbsinit': unreferenced inline function has been removed
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\wchar.h(209): warning C4514: 'wmemcmp': unreferenced inline function has been removed
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\wchar.h(268): warning C4514: 'wmemchr': unreferenced inline function has been removed
    creating C:\Users\l\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hyxyhu1h\pdftotext\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\l\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\l\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" poppler-cpp.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_pdftotext build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\pdftotext.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pdftotext.cp37-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\pdftotext.cp37-win_amd64.lib
    LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'poppler-cpp.lib'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
```

---

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\l\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\l\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hyxyhu1h\\pdftotext\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\l\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hyxyhu1h\\pdftotext\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\l\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-rhe9mc37\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\l\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\pdftotext' Check the logs for full command output.`
```

I have also tried the apprachwith copying to program files but that gave me the same result. Any suggestions on what I might do to fix this?