# pdf2image on windows keeps producing error

Tags: python, windows, poppler

I am trying to write some code to extract text from pdf and followed the directions on pypi to install pdf2image and poppler on windows. I also changed Path. Well, the suggested command on python does not work, it keeps producing the following error:

```
== RESTART: C:\Users\Elisabeth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\test.py ==
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Elisabeth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 441, in pdfinfo_from_path
    proc = Popen(command, env=env, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\Elisabeth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Elisabeth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
```

The code I used:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

from pdf2image.exceptions import (
PDFInfoNotInstalledError,
PDFPageCountError,
    PDFSyntaxError
)

images = convert_from_path(r'C:\Users\Elisabeth\Documents\Anleitungen\C:/Users/Elisabeth/Documents/Anleitungen/t490s_x390_ug_de.pdf')
```

What I did to solve the problem, but did not work:
uninstalling poppler and pdf2path and installing it again. I also used different versions of poppler.

I am just stuck, is there the possibility for some help?

Thank`s

Elaisa

Comment: Look at your file path: `r'C:\Users\Elisabeth\Documents\Anleitungen\C:/Users/Elisabeth/Documents/Anleitungen/t490s_x390_ug_de.pdf'`

Comment: Thank you for the hint, the filepath was wrong, but changing it did not help unfortunately. The error keeps occuring.

Comment: I solved the problem myself - since I am a beginner at python it took a while.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself - since I am a beginner at Python it took a while. I followed the mentioned instructions to install Poppler on Windows. I tried out different things: What did not work was changing path, even after restarting the system. I tried to install different versions of Poppler, that did not help either. So I tried this:  [How to install Poppler on Windows?][1][link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63774687/15779150). That worked very well, you just have to really watch out where the folder "bin" within the Poppler folder is. This seems to differ in the different versions of Poppler.