# Installing Poppler for Windows without using package manage for Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, poppler, poppler-utils

I have gone thru [How to install Poppler on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381713/how-to-install-poppler-on-windows/62615998) Currently I do not use a package manager for Windows, like conda or scoop or chocolatey, and I wish to install poppler-utils without using a package manager. Is there a setup.exe which I can download and run? What else are my options?
The link: http://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/ which is referred to in the above SO thread is not working any more.

Some context:
In our Python 3.10 project, we are using textract 1.5.0 to read a PDF and it seems extract requires poppler-utils to be installed. The poppler-utils is included in the Dockerfile using:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends pkg-config poppler-utils
```

The code to read PDF works when deployed in Azure through Docker image configured for Linux Debian. But the code does not work on my development system which is on Windows. This is a legacy code which was developed by the earlier team and now I need to figure out how to make it work on my local system in order to replicate issues.

Comment: How do I add to "boot up environmental list"? Do you mean it has to be added to PATH or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The Poppler binaries for Windows, including dependencies, are maintained and regularly updated on GitHub by user [oschwartz10612](https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows#:%7E:text=Poppler%20Packaged%20for%20Windows,data)

Add the bin/ directory from the extracted Poppler package to your system's PATH environment variable.

executing the command `pdftoppm -h`. If Poppler is correctly installed and configured, this command should display help information related to the pdftoppm utility.